# Compare the strings of a vector to other strings R

Tags: r, string, vector, string-comparison

I have a vector with strings as followed `dna<-c("ACU","GUA","TCA")` and I want to compare those one by one. For example, I want to see `if(dna[i] == "ACU")` and then proceed to replacing the `dna[i]` with a single letter like this `dna[i] == "L"`.

Any suggestions? I am really new in R, sorry if this is a stupid question.

Comment: i posted something i found useful below, but it looks like it doesnt actually replace the vector for the whole duration of the program. When i tried executing it with a the vector "dna<-c("AUU","CGA","UUU")"  my output was like that "> replace(dna,dna=="CGA","R")
[1] "AUU" "R"   "UUU"
> replace(dna,dna=="CGG","R")
[1] "AUU" "CGA" "UUU" " so it doesn't seem to change it for the whole duration of the execution.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the answer is this `replace(dna,dna=="ACU","L")`. Sorry for the trouble. Hope this will help anyone else who has the same question.